# Netty: The right way to log message to files

Tags: netty

I want to log connection records to files in Netty application. But `log.info("XXXX")` can issue an I/O request which will block current NIO thread causing a performance problem.

So what is the best way to log message in Netty?

Comment: Use asynchronous logging, almost all popular logging library like log4j, logback have asynchronous appender. And also log4j2 as Nicholas mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an issue for you, I would take a look at one of the asynchronous logging frameworks for Java. Here's a couple that have a good reputation for being extremely fast and low latency:

- [Chronicle Logger](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Logger)
- [Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html)

Comment: Thanks, it took me about an hour to migrate from log4j1X to log4j2

Comment: Nice. How's it compare ?

Comment: The xml configuration file's format is totally different. I spent most of the time on rewriting config files...